# How to fix “ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found.” when using autojump on macOS

Tags: python

when type in `j` in shell, we will receive error message like this

```
ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type md5
ERROR:root:code for hash sha1 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha1
ERROR:root:code for hash sha224 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha224
ERROR:root:code for hash sha256 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha256
ERROR:root:code for hash sha384 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha384
ERROR:root:code for hash sha512 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha512
```

Comment: For me this was ultimately caused by some virtualenv setup steps in my .bash_profile which I wasn't really using anyway. I just got rid of those and didn't worry about brew python2, etc.

Answer (score 11):

The problem is that python2 was EOL since Jan 1st, 2020.

On the other hand, `brew` no longer support `python@2` as well. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60229970/aws-cli-errorrootcode-for-hash-md5-was-not-found, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60298514/brew-reinstalling-python2)

trying to uninstall python2 with `brew uninstall python@2` is an option.

```
$ brew uninstall python@2
Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1... (4,169 files, 76.0MB)
```

Comment: solved it for me thanks! Also upgraded my outdated python3.

Comment: If there are any errors, `brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies python@2`, pulled from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61598827/26510)

Comment: uninstall worked for me

Answer (score 10):

What solved for me was linking openssl back to 1.02 to make python2.7 working again.
Check if openssl 1.0.2 is intalled:

```
ls /usr/local/Cellar/openssl
```

which should show: `1.0.2r`

Now link openssl to 1.0.2r:

```
brew switch openssl 1.0.2r
```

Comment: had to switch to 1.0.2s

Comment: @Amit When you did `ls`  did it show 1.0.2.s for you?

Comment: @VijayKumar, yes, so i switched to 1.0.2s

Comment: solved an issue i was having in aws cli aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id

Comment: I think the real solution here is to [upgrade the aws cli](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51136525/26510), and if it fails, pay attention to the top rated comment, ie `brew link --overwrite awscli`